# WPF forms crashed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, devexpress, desktop-application

Is there any way to catch the crashed form and reopen it again.

```
public static void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
       
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting `e.Handled` to `true`? Note that this will leave the application in an undefined state but it will keep it running.

Comment: @mm8 yes e.Handled is true, but I want the same form reopen again after it crashed.

Comment: You will be better off trying to find why your application is crashing and fixing that than trying to reopen a crashing app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `e.Handler` to `true` should prevent the app from shutting down. You will then have to write some code to bring the window up again. There is no "reopen the crashed form" switch I am afraid. There is not even any notion of a "crashed form" as far as the event handler is concerned.

Please also note that keeping an application running like this will leave it in an undefined state. What you really should do is to catch the exception where it occurs and then use the `Dispatcher_UnhandledException` event handler as a last resort for logging any unhandled exception, perhaps displaying a user friendly message and finally shutting the application down.